# Does the equation $x^3-9=0$ have any solutions in $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is my first time "solving an equation" in a group so I feel like that may be the source of my troubles. Here's what I have so far, although I'm not sure how to progress:

> Assume $c$ is a solution to $x^3-9=0$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})$.
>   We then have $$c^3-9=0\implies c^3=9 \implies |c^3|=|9|$$ and since on
>   the LHS we're multiplying elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})$, we
>   consider the order of $[9]_{31}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})^*$
>   which is $15$ since $$9^{15} \equiv 1 \ \text{mod} \ 31.$$ Thus
>   $|c^3|=15$.

I feel like I should be able to deduce $|c|$ from $|c^3|$ but it doesn't seem to be clear to me. Could someone assist me in figuring out how to get $|c|$?

From there, my next steps would be to ensure it divides $31$. Since $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})^*$ is abelian and cyclic thus has an element of maximal finite order of $31$, and if $|c| \leq 31$ then $|c|$ must divide $31.$

Comment: What is $|9|$? I assumed you meant the order of $9$ in $\mathbb Z_{31}$, but you later say "the order of $[9]_{31}$."

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant them both to be the same thing -- $9 \in (\mathbb{Z} / 31 \mathbb{Z})^*$ is the same as $[9]_{31} \in (\mathbb{Z} / 31 \mathbb{Z})^*$ (because isn't the order of $9$ in that group the same thing as the order of anything from its equivalence class, $[9]_{31}$?)

Comment: +1 for the q because a seemingly simple problem evokes multiple solution techniques.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no solution as

$$c^{30} = 9^{10} = 5$$

but $$c^{30} = 1 \ \ \forall c \not =0$$

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't known that $c^{30}=1 \ \ \forall c$. In general do we have that for primes $p$  that $x^{p-1}=1$  $\forall x \in (\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^*$? Nevertheless my question has been answered and I will look more into this. Thank you again!

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: Yes, that is true. Either by Fermat's theorem or using the fact the group is cyclic.

Comment: Mhmmm, just was typing my follow-up comment now, admittedly I feel quite silly ahahaha! I just realized $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ has order $p-1$ and is cyclic, hence has an element of order $p-1$, not $p$ like I thought in the OP. Then since the order of every element must divide $p-1$ so of course $x^{p-1}=1 \ \ \forall x \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$. Thank you once more!

Comment: Is there a way to do this problem by looking at $|c|$? This is Aluffi's suggestion. Using the fact that the $|9|=15$, "if c is a solution of the equation, what can you say about |c|?"

Answer (score 2):

If $x^3=9$ then $x^{15}=9^5$. So $9^5\equiv 1\pmod{31}$. (Since $9^5\not\equiv -1$ , or $9^{15}\equiv -1$ and hence $9$ would not be a square modulo $31$.)

So you only need to check if $9^5\equiv 1\pmod{31}$.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand how $x^{15} = 9^5 \implies 9^5 \equiv 1 \ \text{mod} \ 31$, could you slightly elaborate on that step?

Comment: $x^{15}\equiv\pm 1\pmod{31}$. But if $x^{15}=-1$ then, by the argument I used, $9^{15}\equiv -1$ and hence $9$ is not a square modulo $31$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach uses a pigeonhole argument.

We have $\bmod 31$:

$2^3\equiv 8, (-3)^3\equiv 4=8/2$

Then $2$ is a cubic residue and so are all powers of $2$ and their negatives, thus:

$\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8, \pm 16$

That is $10$ nonzero residues, whereas the total number of cubic nonzero residues must be $(31-1)/3=10$.  Perforce there is no possibility left for $9$ or any other nonzero residue to be a cubic one.

As a corrollary, $3$ shall be a primitive root since this cannot be cubic (above), quadratic (QR), or fifth power ($3^3 \not \equiv \pm 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Ummm  $3$ is a cube $\pmod p$ for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ if and only if we can express
$$  p = x^2 + xy + 61 y^2  $$
in integers. [Theorem due to Jacobi.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa57/aa5724.pdf) A version in Ireland and Rosen.

Let's see, if $3$ is a cube so is $9.$ If $9$ is a cube so are $81$ and $3$

Primes 1 mod 3 up to 1000 that do not work

```
  7,     13,     19,     31,     37,     43,     79,     97,    109,    127,
139,    157,    163,    181,    199,    211,    223,    229,    241,    277,
283,    313,    331,    337,    349,    373,    379,    397,    409,    421,
433,    457,    463,    487,    541,    571,    601,    607,    631,    673,
691,    709,    733,    739,    751,    769,    811,    823,    829,    859,
877,    883,    907,    937,
```

primes 1 mod 3 up to 1000 that do work

```
  1,     61,     67,     73,    103,    151,    193,    271,    307,    367,
439,    499,    523,    547,    577,    613,    619,    643,    661,    727,
757,    787,    853,    919,    967,    991,    997,
```

Comment: When I search for "theorem of jacobi" I get multiple results that do not seem congruent to the claim.  Can you give a more precise reference?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  see article by Hudson and Williams, http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa57/aa5724.pdf

Comment: Thanks, pls place this in the answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  As the degree (3) is so small, the way they describe the result of Jacobi is equivalent to saying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p = u^2 + uv + 61 v^2$ means $x^3-3$ is reducible $\pmod p,$ in fact three distinct linear factors. If $p = 7 u^2 + 3uv + 9 v^2$ instead, irreducible. Finally, for $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ one root. Oh, I guess $3$ is a cube $\pmod 3$

Answer (score 0):

All numbers $a$ coprime to $31$ satisfy $a^{30}\equiv 1 \bmod 31$. There is a primitive root $g$ such that $k=30$ is the smallest positive value such that $g^k\equiv 1 \bmod 31$, so any number coprime to $31$ can be expressed as equivalent to a power of $g$. This means that for $a^6$, in particular, there are only $5$ distinct values possible, since $a^6\in\equiv \{g^6,g^{12},g^{18},g^{24},g^{30}\equiv 1\}$

We can also see that $2^5\equiv 1 \bmod 31$, so also $\{4^5, 8^5, 16^5\}\equiv  1 \bmod 31$. $30/6 = 5$ and thus $e=\{1,2,4, 8, 16\} $ are the $5$ possible values that can have $a^6\equiv e \bmod 31$.

Obviously $9$ is a square, so if $9$ is also a cube $(c^3\equiv 9 \bmod 31)$ then it must also be a sixth power $(d^6\equiv 9 \bmod 31)$ .
Thus  $(c^3\equiv 9 \bmod 31)$ has no solutions $c$.

Answer (score -1):

Slightly more efficiently, we get that if $c^3\equiv 9\equiv 3^2\pmod{31}$, then $c^{15}\equiv 3^{10}\pmod{31}$.

$$3^{10}\equiv (27)^3\cdot 3$$

$$\equiv (-4)^3\cdot 3\equiv -64\cdot 3$$

$$\equiv -2\cdot 3\equiv -6\pmod{31},$$

Since $\left(c^{15}\right)^2\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ for all $c\in\mathbb Z$ such that $31\not\mid c$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),

we get $31\mid \left(c^{15}+1\right)\left(c^{15}-1\right)$,

so $31\mid c^{15}+1$ or $31\mid c^{15}-1$ by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma),

so $c^{15}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{31}$, contradiction.

((In fact, $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\pmod{p}$ for all $a\in\mathbb Z$, odd primes $p$ by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)))

((and also, in this case, $c^{15}\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, because

if $c^{15}\equiv -1\pmod{31}$,

then $\left(3^5\right)^2\equiv -1\pmod{31}$,

contradiction, because $-1$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $31=4\cdot 7+3$ by [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B11_and_the_first_supplement)))