# Solve $y^4 \equiv 5 \bmod{21} $

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I started learning number theory, specifically polynomial congruences, and need help to understand a specific part in the solution of the following exercise. Here it is:

> Solve the polynomial congruence $y^4 \equiv 5 \bmod{21} \quad (1)$

When I first solved the above congruence and since $21 = 3 \times 7$,  I tried to find the solutions to the two congruences

$$y^4 -5 \equiv 0 \bmod{3} \quad \text{and} \quad y^4 - 5 \equiv 0 \bmod{7}.$$

We can reduce the first congruence to $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod{3}$ to simplify calculations. Testing every possible values we easily see that neither congruence has a solution. Therefore, the polynomial congruence $(1)$ has no solution in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$. This is how I solved the problem. However...

The solution given in my textbook only consider the congruence $y^4 -5 \equiv 0 \bmod{3}$ to conclude that $(1)$ has no solutions. So here's my question : why is it sufficient for one congruence to have no solution to conclude that $(1)$ has no solution?

Comment: Any root mod $\color{#c00}3\cdot 7$ persists as a root mod $\color{#c00}3$ because congruences persist mod $\rm\color{#c00}{divisors}$ of the modulus, i.e. $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!\color{#c00}nk}\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid nk\mid a\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid a\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv b\pmod{\! \color{#c00}n}$ $\ \ $

Comment: Usually with modular arithmetic, for equality you say $a=(b\mod n)=(c\mod n)$ (parentheses optional), but for congruence, you say $a\equiv b\equiv c\pmod n$ using the `\pmod` command—unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, good to know. I figured I might be wrong.

Comment: @Michael Many errors are common too, and the OP's notation is indeed erroneous.

Comment: @Chase No, your critique is quite correct.

Comment: @BillDubuque Interesting, TY. I suppose the language of math might be a bit like that which we speak—how long is a grammatical "error" really erroneous before we accept it as an evolution? It's easy to assert ourselves over others on the grounds of "correctness," but the point of language is to communicate ourselves, so if we're correcting others, then obviously intentions were communicated in the first place. Then again, I suppose one of the appeals of math is that it is far more concrete than spoken language. Another example that comes to mind is $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ vs. $\{a,b\}\subset\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Chase There are persuasive reasons why number theorists don't condone that abuse of notaition, e.g.. beginners are often confused about $\bmod$ the ternary relation vs. binary operation, so conflating their notation greatly heightens such confusion.

Comment: As a side note, I just found that for the “binary” mod, in MathJax you should use `\bmod` as in $a=b\bmod n$

Comment: @Chase That too is poor notation. What does it mean $\, a = (b\bmod n)\,$ or $\, (a\bmod n) = (b\bmod n)\,$ or, equivalently, $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!n}?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I guess I don't know, hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction:

Suppose that $y^4\equiv 5\pmod{21}$ had a solution.  Then you would know that $21$ divides $y^4-5$, by the definition of equivalence in modular arithmetic.  Since $3$ divides $21$, it follows that $3$ also divides $y^4-5$.  This would imply, by the definition of equivalence in modular arithmetic, that $y^4\equiv 5\pmod 3$.  This, however, doesn't have a solution, so our original assumption must have been wrong.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what would be the group-theoretic approach to this problem? Would it be like [this previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381605/does-the-equation-x3-9-0-have-any-solutions-in-mathbbz-31-mathbbz) but with the equation $$x^4-5=0$$ in $(\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z 21)$?

Comment: @Andrew $\ $ **Hint** $\ 1\equiv y^{\large 12}\equiv 5^{\large 3}\equiv -1\pmod{\!21}\,\Rightarrow\, 21\mid 2\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\ $ is the analog of your linked answer.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek The group theoretic result would be to look at the image of $y$ under the map $\mathbb{Z}/21\mapsto (\mathbb{Z}/21)/(3\mathbb{Z}/21)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: @BillDubuque @ MichaelBurr Thank you guys for your answers! Bill, in trying to follow your approach I ended up with:
$$x^4-5=0 \implies x^4=5 \implies x^{12}=5^3=1 \implies x=1 \implies x^4-5= -4= 0 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow$$
is this still a valid way of approaching this? 

And Michael, does that "fractional" notation mean quotients? (I'm one chapter away from them, but I'd love to reread it when I study them!)

Comment: @Andrew That's a slightly different way of presenting it. I simply cubed $\,y^4\equiv 5.\ $ Note that you need to argue that $y$ is coprime to $21$ to apply Euler $\phi.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, final comment reply, but where did I (inadvertently) use $\phi$? Doesn't $x^4=5 \implies (x^4)^3=5^3 \implies x^{12} = 5^3$, and $[5]_{21}^3 = [1]_{21}$, thus $x^{12}=1 \implies x=1$?

Comment: Oh wait.. $x^{12} =1 \not \Rightarrow x=1$.. My mistake! Thank you and sorry for taking up your time!

Comment: @Andrew It's true for $x$ coprime to $21$ by Euler (if you don't know Euler then use little Fermat mod $3$ and $7).\,$

Comment: @Andrew Essentially what I did is apply a slight generalization of [Euler's criterion for squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) (which has a natural group-theoretic view). You can find many other examples [in other answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20euler%27s%20criterion%20)

Comment: @Andrew Yes, all the fraction bars are quotients (and I'm using the isomorphism theorems).